# Where is the Python startup banner defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm compiling several different versions of Python for my system, and I'd like to know where in the source the startup banner is defined so I can change it for each version. For example, when the interpreter starts it displays

```
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 28 2013, 10:19:42) 
[GCC 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I'd like to change the string `default` to other things to signal which version I'm using, but I'm also interested in how the whole shebang is assembled. Where is this defined?

Comment: You could probably ack for `__DATE__` or `__TIME__` to get to the related code.

Comment: You could use this code to change what the interpreter shows - python -ic 'import sys; sys.ps1="$ "; sys.ps2=""'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's use `grep` to get in the ballpark.  I'm not going to bother searching for `default` because I'll get too many results, but I'll try `Type "Help"`, which should not appear too many times.  If it's a C string, the quotes will be escaped.  We should look for C strings first and Python strings later.

```
Python $ grep 'Type \\"help\\"' . -Ir
./Modules/main.c:    "Type \"help\", \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" " \
```

It's in `Modules/main.c`, in `Py_Main()`.  More digging gives us this line:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Python %s on %s\n",
    Py_GetVersion(), Py_GetPlatform());
```

Because "on" is in the format string, `Py_GetPlatform()` must be `linux` and `Py_GetVersion()` must give the string we want...

```
Python $ grep Py_GetVersion . -Irl
...
./Python/getversion.c
...
```

That looks promising...

```
PyOS_snprintf(version, sizeof(version), "%.80s (%.80s) %.80s",
              PY_VERSION, Py_GetBuildInfo(), Py_GetCompiler());
```

We must want `Py_GetBuildInfo()`, because it's inside the parentheses...

```
Python $ grep Py_GetBuildInfo . -Irl
...
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c
...
```

That looks a little too obvious.

```
const char *
Py_GetBuildInfo(void)
{
    static char buildinfo[50 + sizeof(HGVERSION) +
                          ((sizeof(HGTAG) > sizeof(HGBRANCH)) ?
                           sizeof(HGTAG) : sizeof(HGBRANCH))];
    const char *revision = _Py_hgversion();
    const char *sep = *revision ? ":" : "";
    const char *hgid = _Py_hgidentifier();
    if (!(*hgid))
        hgid = "default";
    PyOS_snprintf(buildinfo, sizeof(buildinfo),
                  "%s%s%s, %.20s, %.9s", hgid, sep, revision,
                  DATE, TIME);
    return buildinfo;
}
```

So, `default` is the name of the Mercurial branch.  By examining the makefiles, we can figure out that this comes from the macro `HGTAG`.  A makefile variable named `HGTAG` produces the variable, and that variable is run as a command.  So,

## Simple solution

When building Python,

```
Python $ ./configure
Python $ make HGTAG='echo awesome'
Python $ ./python
Python 3.2.3 (awesome, May  1 2013, 21:33:27) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the first part of the output is the Python version string as returned by `Py_GetVersion`. The stuff in parentheses (including `default`) is part of the string returned by `Py_GetBuildInfo`, which suggests to me that it can probably be tweaked at compile time.

Comment: Well done for writing this post like a detective story. Makes for thrilling reading!

Comment: Please note that since the move to git-based version management, the Makefile macro is now called `GITTAG`. Basically, everywhere you see `hg` or `HG` in the answer above, replace it with `git` or `GIT`, respectively. @Dietrich, if you'd like to "modernize" your answer, go ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if you add a mercurial tag before you build, then `default` will be replaced with the name of your tag (source: `Modules/getbuildinfo.c` : `_Py_hgidentifier()`)

Basically seems like it chooses the name `default` because that is the name of the branch. Looks like the interpreter is built with the tag name, if one exists, or the name of the branch if no tag (besides `tip`) exists on the current working copy.